# MSB3721 ERROR and A2008 ERROR: When building MASM application in VS2022

Tags: assembly, masm, visual-studio-2022

Im learning assembly in school and in the first sample problem I am having issues getting things to build. The sample problem is giving me a lot of errors even though I followed the example line for line. I dont have any experience with Assembly / MASAM so debugging the issue is very difficult.

My code is as follows:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.code
main PROC
    mov EAX, 5
    add EAX, 6

    INVOKE ExitProcess,0

main ENDP
END
```

In theory, im suppose to be able to add two integers together. However im receiving several build errors:

> MSB3721: Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   MSB3721 The command "ml64.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"x64\Debug\main.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Tamain.asm" exited with code 1.  Lab02   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets  70

I am using a Windows 10 x64 - Intel Core I7 Processor. The build dependencies were set to MASM(.targets, .props)

Some other errors im also getting:

> CODE: A2008 - syntax error: .  on the line with "ExitProcess PROTO"

> CODE: A2008 - syntax error: . on the line with ".code"

> CODE: A2008 - syntax error: . on the line with ".386"

So I have quite a few errors with little information to work with. Could someone perhaps help me resolve these issues or let me know if there is some weird setup I can do in Visual Studio to use assembly code.

Comment: Remove the `,` from the line `ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD`.

Comment: `ml64.exe` <-- That's MASM for x86-64 targets, you want the one for x86 targets (`ml.exe`). You need to find the option in Visual Studio that controls whether to build your application as 32- or 64-bit and set it to 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Michael's comment is absolutely correct. Just go to "**Build->Configuration Manager**" and change **Active solution platform** to **x86**